# Spring Security Tomcat 6.x vs Tomcat 7.x Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: tomcat, spring-security

Currently I am working in an application using Spring security to login.

Spring Security 3.2.7.RELEASE with Tomcat 6.0.43

Iam trying to upgrade the application to Tomcat 7.0.62.

Below is part of my configuration. I have noticed that the in Tomcat 6.0.43 the SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter contains the authentication: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). But when running in Tomcat 7.0.62 it does not.

I can't figure out why this occurrs, because of this the missing authentication it keeps bumping into the Full authentication is required to accesss this resource in the exceptionTranslationFilter.

Maybe someone has a tip or direction to look into?

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/error/*"
            filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/back*"
            filters="none" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/j_spring_security_check*"
            filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="logoutFilter, httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<bean id="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />

<bean id="securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" />

<bean id="anonymousProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="key" value="changeThis" />
    <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
            <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
            <property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.jsp" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after stripping down my application I discovered that the cookie-config in the web.xml was the reason it did not work:

```
   <session-config>
        <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Removing the cookie-config solved my problem because obviously you can arrange this in the server.xml / context.xml of the tomcat.